# Pytesseract OCR wrong text recognition

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

When I use Pytesseract to recognise the text in this image, Pytesseract returns ***7A51k*** but the text in this image is ***7,451k***.

How can I fix this problem with code instead of providing a clearer source image?

[image]

my code

```
import pytesseract as pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D:\\App\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'

img = Image.open("captured\\amount.png")
string = pytesseract.image_to_string(image=img, config="--psm 10")

print(string)
```

Comment: Sometime OCR can fail to find the text.
But in some case, the success rate can be improved with several little trick. One of the best-know trick is simply to resize the image.
You can try it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382174/increase-accuracy-of-text-recognition-through-pytesseract-pil

Comment: but the image is too small so when I resize it, it will become blurry

Comment: You can try inverted image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a two-step solution

---

- 1. Resize the image
- 2. Apply thresholding.

---

- 1. Resizing the image

  - The input image is too small for recognizing the digits, punctuation, and character. Increasing the dimension will enable an accurate solution.
- 2. Apply [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

  - Thresholding will show the features of the image.
  - When you apply thresholding result will be:

    - [image]

When you read the threshold image:

```sh
7,451k
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("4ARXO.png")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
img = cv2.resize(img, (w*3, h*3))
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem if the image is blurry after resizing, you can threshold it, and invert it as [AlexAlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13226440/alex-alex) has proposed:

> output: 7,451k

```py
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2

# Read Image
gray = cv2.imread('2.png', 0)

# Resize
gray = cv2.resize(gray, (600,200))

# Inverting
gray = 255 - gray
emp = np.full_like(gray, 255)
emp -= gray

# Thresholding
emp[emp==0] = 255
emp[emp<100] = 0

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(emp, config='outputbase digits')

print(text)
```